# How to replace fragment in BaseAdapter?

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment

#### My Adapter :

```
public class MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    ...
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View view = mLayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.my_listview_item, null);

    TextView myTv = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.myTv);
    myTv.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // I want to replace another fragment
        }
    });

    return view;
}
```

I can't find a solution in stackoverflow...
Can I replace a fragment?? Help me..

Comment: Use `interface` for it.

Comment: Do you have a example code?

Comment: Have you checked the answer? You need to give some feedback almost.

Comment: Not yet.. It's hard for me.. I'm depressed.. OMG

Comment: Its not hard. I have already implemented a code for you. Just read my answer step by step.

Comment: Because this code was working for me. So obvious it will work for you!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two ways to call fragment from adapter class :

1) You can make a interface for it.

2) You can register your own `BroadcastReceiver` with particular action.

Direct call fragment from button click is not a good and right , clean way. So i am just going to post answer for my second approach.

On button click in your adapter class

```
context.sendBroadcast(new Intent("call.myfragment.action"))
```

This is the simple things in android is by sending broadcast messages.

```
urButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        context.sendBroadcast(new Intent("call.myfragment.action"))

    }
});
```

Now in your activity all you need to register a `BroadcastReceiver` with the `"call.myfragment.action"` and that's it inside of it just call your fragment:

```
context.registerReceiver(mBroadcastReceiver, new IntentFilter("call.myfragment.action")) // This code is in your Activity will be in onCreate() or in onResume() method.


BroadcastReceiver mBroadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        // Now just call your Fragment here now.
    }
};
```

Comment: call.myfragment.action <- Is this alias? or fragment name?

Comment: It a method name which is registering for brodcast receiver through IntentFilter.

Comment: Its impossible. Any error are you getting? Have you checked in `onReceive()` method is calling or not

Comment: my onReceive method -> Intent in = new Intent("com.me.myFragment"); startActivity(in); // Error receiving broadcast Intent.. blabla

Comment: @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        // Now just call your Fragment here now.
    } In this method How are you calling your fragment??

Comment: Intent in = new Intent("com.me.myFragment"); startActivity(in);

Comment: No. This is totally wrong. You need to use this `Fragment frag = new myFragment(); 

FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction(); 

ft.replace(R.id.fragment_container, frag);  

ft.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_FADE); 

ft.addToBackStack(null); 

ft.commit();`

Comment: fragment_container is the id of your fragment container.

Answer (score 1):

add in your class adapter this attribute and init in your constructor :

```
private FragmentActivity fragmentActivity;
```

when init your adapter, add getActivity() :

```
YourAdapter yourAdapter = new YourAdapter(getContext(), this.myList, getActivity());
```

in your class adapter click listener method :

```
            public void onClick(View view) {
                fragmentActivity.getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().
                        remove(fragmentActivity.getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.frame)).commit();
                YourFragment frag = new YourFragment();
                fragmentActivity.getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.frame, frag).commit();
        }
    });
```

work perfectly !!!

Answer (score 0):

You have two ways:

1- Pass your fragment or activity to your adapter and have a reference to that. In `onClick()` method, use it to replace fragment.

2- Have a `BroadcastReceiver` that replaces the fragment. Then in `onClick()` method, simply send a BroadCast.

Answer (score 0):

You can use fragment manager to pop or repalce your fragment.
A fragment is tied to actvity,

```
FragmentTransaction  trans = mStack.getInstance().beginTransaction();

trans.replace(R.id.fragment_container, mFragment,
      mFragment.getCustomTag());

   trans.addToBackStack(mFragment.getCustomTag())
         .commitAllowingStateLoss();
getSupportFragmentManager().executePendingTransactions();
mStack.setTopFragment(mFragment, mFragment.getCustomTag());
```